# Is the set of all Lebesgue-measurable sets measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I consider the set $X^p=\{A\subseteq[0,1]|A$ Lebesgue-measurable and $\lambda(A)=p\}$ for a $p\in (0,1]$. My objective is to construct a random variable with values in $X^p$. Therefore I need to know how to construct a non-trivial and atomless measure on $X^p$. Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

On a more general note, is there any set with cardinality $\beth_2$ that is measurable with respect to a non-trivial and atomless measure?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense (I think). (Lebesgue) measurability only makes sense for subsets of $\Bbb{R}^d$. But $X^p \subset \mathcal{P}([0,1])$ (the powerset of $[0,1]$). But to construct such a random variable, you can just use $\mathcal{P}(X^p)$ as the $\sigma$-algebra on $X^p$, fix some $A_0 \in X^p$ and let the probability measure be $\delta_{A_0}$ (the dirac measure at $A_0$). Then take $X(A) = A$ for $A \in X^p$.

Comment: On $\Bbb{R}$, you cannot use the power set **if you want something like the Lebesgue measure**, i.e. there is no **translation invariant** measure $\lambda$ on the whole power set such that $\lambda([a,b]) = b-a$ for all $a<b$. But if you only use something like the dirac measure (i.e. $\delta_{A_0}(M) = 1$ if $A_0 \in M$ and $\delta_{A_0}(M)=0$ otherwise for $M \subset X^p$), you **can** use the whole power set.

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify what I mean by non-trivial to rule out the dirac measure.

Comment: Some people do study "random sets". Search for it, it may answer some of your questions.

Comment: What does $\aleph_2$ have to do with anything? Maybe you mean $\beth_2$. In any case, you can assign a measure to $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ by considering the product measure on $2^{\Bbb R}$. There you can show that the set of Lebesgue measurable sets is non-measurable.

Comment: @Matthias: They seem to use random sets for stochastics. I only heard the terms.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the suggestion. I corrected $\beth$ in the question. Can you point me to any references on the product measure on $2^{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/q/102386/7206 has some nice answers.